# Create row with unique ID in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my javascript function to add new row to `<table>` in HTML. I need a unique row id for each table row. Below is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var html = '<tr><td class="cb"><input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="inputString" name="inputString"/><div id="showList"><ul class="list-group"></ul></div></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="debit" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="credit" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control"></td><td><input class="btn btn-warning" type="button" name="remove" id="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeMe(this);"></td></tr>';
        
        var x=1;
        
        $("#add").click(function(){
            
            $("#table_field").append(html);
        });
});
```

How can I achieve this in the same function

I tried creating unique ids but not able to do.. Please help me

Comment: "*I need a unique row id*" - no, no you don't.   Or at least it's *very* unlikely you do - what do you think you need that id for?  There's likely a better solution.

Comment: Keep a counter of the current number of rows, so that you can increase it by one and append it to the ID as suffix, when a new row gets added. Or - and that is often the better alternative - _stop using IDs_ to find your relevant elements; and use the relation the elements have to each other in the DOM, to find the _correct_ element to work on in each instance.

Comment: what you want to achieve by giving unique id to row?. you can give uniqueId by using Rand() function of javascript with current timespan

Comment: I have implemented auto search ...so for every row input search is there. but it works for only first row of table & not with newly added rows

Comment: Cant you just use [`HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) as identifier?

Comment: *I have implemented auto search* - I can't see how that would even *use* a unique tr id, let alone *need* one.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a unique row id for each table row.

To add an `id` to each row while adding you just have to pass it on `$("#table_field").append()`. Below I am using the `length` of `tr` inside `#table_field` to set an `id`.

```js
$("#add").click(() => {
  const
    tTable = $("#table_field"),
    tID = `tr${tTable.find('tr').length}`;

  tTable.append(
    `<tr id = '${tID}'><td>${tID}</td></tr>`
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id = 'table_field'></table>
<button id = 'add'>Add</button>
```

*You can adjust the logic of generating the `id` to how you see fit. Like using [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) or [`Date ticks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).*